# Abstract class as parameters in Spring method

Tags: spring, parameters, abstract

I have an abstract class named "AbstractDTO". My purpose is to have a method adnotated with RequestMapping "/info", which receives as a parameter an AbstractDTO, but recognizes in the method the concrete class of the object sent as a parameter, something like "FirstDTO". How can I do that?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear... Do you want to cast the received asbtract dto instance inside your controller method? Do you want to deserialize to a concrete dto instance, without knowing which the concrete class is? Please clarify.

Comment: I want to deserialize to a concrete dto instance, without knowing which the concrete class is.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it out, but to make this work you should create a [`RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.html) bean on which you can set a [custom argument resolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.html#setCustomArgumentResolvers-java.util.List-).

That argument resolver implements interface [`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html) and takes care of converting what's received via HTTP to an instance of the relevant subclass of `AbstractDTO`.

For more details see [Defining `@RequestMapping` handler methods](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-methods) in the Spring Framework reference documentation, and the API docs that I linked to above.